# have HTTP error "Unable to compile class for JSP"

Tags: maven, jsp, netbeans

I am working in a JSP project. While runnning the project using Netbeans with Tomcat 7.0.68 server, I got the following exception,

HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

**type** Exception report

**message** Unable to compile class for JSP:

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\work\Catalina\localhost\Rites1\org\apache\jsp\Register_jsp.java]
The import com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\work\Catalina\localhost\Rites1\org\apache\jsp\Register_jsp.java]
Syntax error on token "(", . expected

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\work\Catalina\localhost\Rites1\org\apache\jsp\Register_jsp.java]
The import String cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\work\Catalina\localhost\Rites1\org\apache\jsp\Register_jsp.java]
Syntax error on tokens, Name expected instead

**Stacktrace**:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
```

I'm building a registration form in a file called Register.jsp in a maven project using netbeans

```html
<%@page import="com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request(
        Object, String, boolean)"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileNotFoundException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JComboBox"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JTextField"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JRadioButton"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Date" %>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");%>


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" ></meta>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/RitesCSS.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Resize.css" media="screen and (max-widht:1000px)"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Menu.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Layout.css"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Register Now</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%!
            public class Followers {

                String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rites";
                String USERNAME = "myusername";
                String PASSWORD = "mypass";

                Connection connection = null;
                PreparedStatement insertUsers = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;

                public Followers() {

                    try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        insertUsers = connection.prepareStatement(
                                "INSERT INTO followers (HajjID,UserName,ID,Phone,Country,Passport,Language,Gender,Photo,Password,State,DOB,adress)"
                                + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
                        );
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }

                public int setFollowers(String HajjID, String UserName, String ID, String Phone, String country, String PassportNo, String Language, String rdoGender, String img, String txtPassword, String States, String DoB, String txtarAddress) {

                    int result = 0;
                    FileInputStream fis = null;
                    File Photo = new File("");
                    img = fis.toString();

                    try {
                        insertUsers.setString(1, HajjID);
                        insertUsers.setString(2, UserName);
                        insertUsers.setString(3, ID);
                        insertUsers.setString(4, Phone);
                        insertUsers.setString(5, country);
                        insertUsers.setString(6, PassportNo);
                        insertUsers.setString(7, Language);
                        insertUsers.setString(8, rdoGender);

                        try {
                            fis = new FileInputStream(Photo);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        insertUsers.setString(9, img);

                        insertUsers.setString(10, txtPassword);
                        insertUsers.setString(11, States);
                        insertUsers.setString(12, DoB);
                        insertUsers.setString(13, txtarAddress);
                        result = insertUsers.executeUpdate();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return result;
                }

            }
        %>
        <%

            int result = 0;

            if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
                String Type = new String();
                String HajjID = new String();
                String UserName = new String();
                String ID = new String();
                String Phone = new String();
                String country = new String();
                String PassportNo = new String();
                String Language = new String();
                String rdoGender = new String();
                String Photo = new String();
                String txtPassword = new String();
                String States = new String();
                String DoB = new String();
                String txtarAddress = new String();

                if (request.getParameter("Type").toString() != null) {
                    Type = request.getParameter("Type").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("HajjID").toString() != null) {
                    HajjID = request.getParameter("HajjID").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("ID").toString() != null) {
                    ID = request.getParameter("ID").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("Phone").toString() != null) {
                    Phone = request.getParameter("Phone").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("country").toString() != null) {
                    country = request.getParameter("country").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("PassportNo").toString() != null) {
                    PassportNo = request.getParameter("PassportNo").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("Language").toString() != null) {
                    Language = request.getParameter("Language").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("rdoGender").toString() != null) {
                    rdoGender = request.getParameter("rdoGender").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("Photo").toString() != null) {
                    Photo = request.getParameter("Photo").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("txtPassword").toString() != null) {
                    txtPassword = request.getParameter("txtPassword").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("States").toString() != null) {
                    States = request.getParameter("States").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("DoB").toString() != null) {
                    DoB = request.getParameter("DoB").toString();
                }
                if (request.getParameter("txtarAddress").toString() != null) {
                    txtarAddress = request.getParameter("txtarAddress").toString();
                }

                Followers users = new Followers();
                result = users.setFollowers(HajjID, UserName, ID, Phone, country, PassportNo, Language, rdoGender, Photo, txtPassword, States, DoB, txtarAddress);

            }


        %>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" action="register.php" method="POST">
            <div id="contaner">
                <div id="header">

                    <img src="logo.jpg" align="left"></img>
                    <h1> Rites</h1> 

                    <li><a href="Register.jsp">Register now</a></li>

                </div>
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.jsp">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.jsp">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
                <div id="mainbody">
                    <div id="pageHeading"> <v>Registeration</v></div>
                    <div id="bodyLeft">

                    </div>
                    <div id="bodyRight"><h5>
                            <form name="registration" action="RegServlet" method="post" id="registerForm">
                                <table id="table1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>User name</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="UserName" id="txt" class='StyleTxtField'/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>ID</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="ID" id="txt" class='StyleTxtField'/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Phone</td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="Phone" id="txt" class='StyleTxtField'/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Country</td>
                                        <td><select name="country" id="txt" class='StyleSelectFiled'>
                                                <option value="">Country...</option>
                                                <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                                                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                                                
                                            </select></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Date of Birth</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="date" name="DoB" id="txt" class='StyleTxtField'/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Address</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <textarea name="txtarAddress" id="txt" class='StyleTxtField'></textarea>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Type</td>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="Type" id="Leader" value="Leader" ><label for="Leader">Leader</label>
                                            <input type="radio" name="Type" id="Follower" value="Follower" onsubmit="setFollowers"><label for="Follower">Follower</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<%= result%>" />
                                    <td><br><button type="reset" id="btm"><m>Reset</m></button>
                                        <button type="submit" id="btm"><m>Register</m></button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table><br>
                            </form></h5>
                        <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
                            <!--
                            function dusplayResults()
                            {

                                if (document.myForm.hidden.value === 1) {

                                    alert("Data Inserted1!");
                                }
                            }
                        </SCRIPT>
                    </div>

                </div>
                
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to do this "if the chosen radio button named "type" is follower insert the data into the follower table, and if the chosen radio button named "type" is leader insert the data into the leader table"

I'm using a database called rites in phpmyadmine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@page import="com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request(
        Object, String, boolean)"%>
```

your import is wrong.

use

```
 <%@ page import="static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.register" %>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for answering
please i need your help
i still have this error 
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.68\work\Catalina\localhost\Rites1\org\apache\jsp\login_jsp.java]
The import com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.register cannot be resolved